# mysql two table join sum not equal result

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `purchase_orders_details` and `stock_orders_details` I show in below of my paragraph

```
purchase_orders_details

--------------------
item_id | item_qty |
--------------------
|   1   |    15    |
|   2   |    10    |
|   1   |    20    |
--------------------

stock_orders_details
------------------------
item_id | item_rcv_qty |
------------------------
|  1 |       10        |
|  2 |        5        |
|  1 |       15        |
------------------------
```

The query example is:

```
SELECT * FROM purchase_orders_details p 
left join stock_details d on p.item_qty=d.item_rcv_qty 
WHERE d.item_rcv_qty IS NULL
```

I want to result like this, and only result show who not matched with `item_qty not equal item_rcv_qty` because when both quantity is equal then order will be completed.

```
-------------------------------------------------
Item Id  | Item Quantity  |  Received Quantity |
-------------------------------------------------
|   1    |   35           |      25            |
|   2    |   10           |       5            |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: where does the 32 come from?

Comment: sorry! its 35 I have to edit this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expected output looks as though you are just aggregating the item quantities and item received quantities for each `item_id`.  If so, then one way to approach this is to join together two subqueries which compute the aggregations you want.

```
SELECT t1.item_id,
       t1.item_qty AS item_quantity,
       COALESCE(t2.item_rcv_qty, 0) AS receieved_quantity
FROM
(
    SELECT item_id, SUM(item_qty) AS item_qty
    FROM purchase_orders_details
    GROUP BY item_id
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT item_id, SUM(item_rcv_qty) AS item_rcv_qty
    FROM stock_orders_details
    GROUP BY item_id
) t2
    ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id
```

Comment: you could have id's in table2 not in table1 :p

Comment: Actually I think we are missing an even bigger point which the OP did a vague job of describing.  In any case, before I write a full outer join, I will wait for feedback.

Comment: ah, ya know, they can figure it out when the reports come out wrong.

Comment: when your query run query return single record

`Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [item_id] => 1
            [item_quantity] => 6
            [receieved_quantity] => 5
        )

)`

but i want record like this

`Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [item_id] => 1
            [item_quantity] => 35
            [receieved_quantity] => 25
        ),
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [item_id] => 2
            [item_quantity] => 10
            [receieved_quantity] => 5
        ),    

)`

Answer (score 0):

I run query and he return this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
      (
        [item_id] => 1
        [item_quantity] => 5
        [receieved_quantity] => 5
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [item_id] => 2
        [item_quantity] => 11
        [receieved_quantity] => 1
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [item_id] => 3
        [item_quantity] => 2
        [receieved_quantity] => 0
    )

)
```

First array have complete `receieved_quantity` but he showing in array, Now I want only these record who has incomplete record.